# Is there a way to get power consumption info from KUKA robot?

Tags: robotics, kuka-krl

I want to make an application for monitoring KUKA robot current state. And there I want to send data about current power consumption but couldn't find any system variable which could be useful for me.

So, the question is is there a posibility to get info about power consumption without additional tech packages or any additional modules?

- Controller: KR C4 compact
- Software: KSS 8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system variable $curr_act is cyclically updated and gives you the current in amps for each axis...[image]

Comment: Thank you! Actually I wanted to get all the energy which is being spent (controller + robot) but it turned out my robot type doesn't support energy measurement. And you answer gives me opportunity to make this

Answer (score 1):

In KSS 8.3 there is a feature for measuring the energy consumption of robot and cabinet combined, see section 4.16 in the documentation for System Integrators

[image]

You have to find out whether your robot type supports that feature or ask KUKA.

I do not know whether you are familiar with the trace / oscilloscope functionality mentioned above. The trace group mentioned can be configured in the menu Diagnosis->Trace->Configuration and viewed via Diagnosis->Trace->Oscilloscope. There seems to be no documentation on the meaning of the recorded channels but you can probably interpret without much explanation.

[image].